# Getting percentage of every .map object

Tags: ruby

I have a string of chars, with each char assigned with a weight using an if block inside of a loop (`.map`). I initialized a total value outside the loop `total_weight = 0`. but since this value is outside the loop it changes with every iteration. I am unsure how to use `total_weight` to calculate the weight percentage for each char since the char weight is only effective inside the loop and `total_weight` is only effective outside the loop, once it has the actual total weight for the whole string.

```
sequence ="AAGCAAGTCCATACGAATATGGCACTAGATCTTGAAGGGAAGTATTTTTTCTACTTTATGGTTAAATAGCTATGATTGAAAGAGTGTAATTGTCAT"


total_weight = 0

char_count =sequence.each_char.tally
puts "length of sequence is #{sequence.length}"

char_count.map do |seq_letter , seq_letter_frequency , weight|
  puts
  puts "there are #{seq_letter_frequency} #{seq_letter} in this sequence"

  if    seq_letter == "A"  ; weight = 331.0

  elsif seq_letter == "T"  ; weight = 321.0

  elsif seq_letter == "G"  ; weight = 347.0

  elsif seq_letter == "C"  ; weight = 307.0

  end
  seq_letter_sum_weight = weight * seq_letter_frequency.to_f

  total_weight += seq_letter_sum_weight

  puts "total_weight keeps changing??? #{total_weight}"

  seq_letter_percent_by_weight = (seq_letter_sum_weight/total_weight) *100.0

  puts
  puts "#{seq_letter} occurs at a #{seq_letter_percent_by_weight}%" # outputted % is incorrect due to the changing @total_weight in the denominator

end
```

Also, is it possible to keep the solution within the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need any loop here, [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) provides all the tools to calculate this in a more readable way.

```rb
weights = {"A" => 331.0, "T" => 321.0, "G" => 347.0, "C" => 307.0}
sequence ="AAGCAAGTCCATACGAATATGGCACTAGATCTTGAAGGGAAGTATTTTTTCTACTTTATGGTTAAATAGCTATGATTGAAAGAGTGTAATTGTCAT"

total = sequence.length 
total_weights = weights.sum { |l, w| sequence.count(l).to_f / total * w }
#⇒ 328.1458333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the objective is to calculate a weighted average of the numbers of occurrences of each distinct letter in the string `sequence`. That can be done as follows.

```
weights = {"A" => 331.0, "T" => 321.0, "G" => 347.0, "C" => 307.0}
```

```
sequence.each_char.
         tally.
         map { |c,n| n*weights[c] }.
         sum.
         fdiv(weights.values.sum)
  #=> 24.120980091883613
```

Note that [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) made its debut in Ruby v2.7.

The steps are as follows.

```
e = sequence.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "AAGCA...CAT":each_char>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to see the values it will generate and pass to `tally`.

```
e.to_a
  #=> ["A", "A", "G", "C", "A",..., "C", "A", "T"]
```

Continuing,

```
h = e.tally
  #=> {"A"=>32, "G"=>20, "C"=>11, "T"=>33} 
a = h.map { |c,n| n*weights[c] }
  #=> [10592.0, 6940.0, 3377.0, 10593.0] 
t = a.sum
  #=> 31502.0
b = weights.values.sum
  #=> 1306.0 
t.fdiv(b)
  #=> 24.120980091883613
```

Notice that if the weights were equal this would compute the simple average of the values of `h`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take at calculating weight of each char presence in the string:

```
sequence = 'AAGCAAGTCCATACGAATATGGCACTAGATCTTGAAGGGAAGTATTTTTTCTACTTTATGGTTAAATAGCTATGATTGAAAGAGTGTAATTGTCAT'
weights = {A: 331.0, T: 321.0, G: 347.0, C: 307.0}
results = weights.map{ |k, v| [k, sequence.count(k.to_s) * v] }.to_h
total_weight = results.values.sum
results.each {|k, v| puts "#{k} occurs at a #{(100 * v / total_weight).round(2)}%"}
```

That outputs following results:

> A occurs at a 33.62%
>
> T occurs at a 33.63%
>
> G occurs at a 22.03%
>
> C occurs at a 10.72%